# Import allways returns null, but ImportConstructor works

Tags: c#, mef, mefedmvvm

I am trying to use MEF in my application, but I have problem with the Import.

```
    [Import (typeof(IUserServices ))]
    public IUserServices UserService { get; private set; }
```

This does not work and UserService is always null.

But using the ImportContstructor in the same class works perfectly:

```
    [ImportingConstructor ]
    public MainWindowVM(
        IUIVisualizerService uiVisualizer,
        IViewAwareStatus viewAwareStatus,
        IMessageBoxService messageBoxService, 
        IManager mwManager,
        TagItemModel tagModel,
        ILibraryModel  documentModel,
        ILibraryServices libraryServices,
        ILogServices logServices ,
        IUserServices userServices)
```

Can anybody help me in the issue. I already spend hours, but did not find any solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you add your code which demonstrates your container creation, and how you are trying to satisfy imports?

Comment: I'm using ChinchV2 together with MefedMVVM to create the container.
Here the code, which provides the export:


[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    [Export (typeof(IUserServices ))]
    public class TestUserServices:IUserServices 
    {
        public void GetSettings(Action<HubSettings, Exception> callback)
        {
            var dPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Remove(0, 6);
            callback(new HubSettings {DataPath = dPath}, null);
        }
    }

Comment: My best guess is that this is an issue with MefedMVVM.  Are you sure it is supposed to support property imports?

Comment: MefedMVVM is based on MEF. Would there be any reason or technical background, that property import should not be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using ChinchV2 together with MefedMVVM to create the container.
Here the code, which provides the export:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
[Export (typeof(IUserServices ))]
public class TestUserServices:IUserServices 
{
    public void GetSettings(Action<HubSettings, Exception> callback)
    {
        var dPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Remove(0, 6);
        callback(new HubSettings {DataPath = dPath}, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: CTRL+K or clicking the `{}` icon above the editor formats code! Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

The property will only be set by MEF after the constructor is fully executed. When are you checking if the property is null?

Comment: That's it. I was always checking during the initialization. Thanks very much!